# How to resend email to recipient who is both in-person and remote signer?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm not sure if this is possible but we have implemented one of our signers to be both remote and in-person (by including the `clientUserID` in the request AND using `signer.EmbeddedRecipientStartURL = "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN";`

By doing this, the signer gets an email but can also sign embedded.

When we modify an envelope (for example by modifying the email subject line) and pass `resendEnvelope=true` to the envelope update API, it only resends the new email to the remote signers.  The signer who is both does not get one.

Is there any way around this or do I unfortunately have to create an all-or-none email scenario where the signer is manually declared either in-person or remote and needs to be removed/re-added by the user in order to convert between them?

Comment: An FYI to anyone looking for a similar answer.  It seems converting from embedded signer to remote isn't as tedious as I thought.  Others were saying I would need to first delete the embedded recipient and add a new recipient as remote, but all I had to do was add or remove the clientUserID with an update API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's a way around this using platform settings only, however you can always just have your app send the email - instead of using a platform generated email notifications - when certain conditions are met.

Since you have the recipient information you have their name and email, so when a given envelope is modified you can call the [Envelopes: get API](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/) to retrieve routing information to know who turn it is etc then generate a signing URL for that recipient, stuff into a branded email, and send it their way.

Comment: That's true.  Thanks Ergin.  At this point we are probably too far down the line.  We just ended up adding the ability to convert a recipient between remote and embedded which was easy enough.  I'll mark this as accepted since I believe you are correct.